Infinte matrix as a bounded linear operator
It is well known that any $ m \times n$  matrix defines a bounded linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m $ through the usual matrix multiplication. Is there any such result for infinte sequences. More precisely, What types of infinite matrices define bounded linear maps from the sequence space $ \ell^p $ to $\ell^q $ for $ 1 \leq p ,q\leq \infty $?
P.S: I feel something like $A=A_{i,j}$ with $\sum_{i,j \in \mathbb{Z}}|a_{i,j}|^q < \infty$ should do. Is there any well known criteria to make it a bounded linear map?

Thanks for your comment. I had a look a look at it. It does not answer my question.

For $p = q = 2$ a sufficient condition is that $\sum_{i, j} |A_{i, j}|^2$ is finite, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator. I assume there is some reasonable generalization of this to other values of $p$ and $q$.

See maybe here
